# JBoss - not working the next day

Tags: jakarta-ee, jboss, single-sign-on, jaas

We are having a problem, our JBoss EAP 6.3 cluster (2 nodes in domain mode + Apache) on a Centos OS, is not working after a period of inactivity (night). Its connected to an ldap. We do login, timesout and get Service Temporarily Unavailable, then reload the page and sometimes works, others no.

We have to restart the server every morning, then its all ok until the next day. What could be the cause of this problem? Can you point us on the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have a Kerberos SSO in our Centos servers, so the problem was related to that. The kerberos ticket only lasts 12 hours and its generated every time we ssh to our servers. So the next day (after a 12 hours period) JBoss could not connect to a network shared folder (because of ticket expiration), does timeout with no error logs related to that.

We already solved the problem, configuring a new ticket every 2 hours.